# Problem with adding two circular progressBar

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar, settimeout

I've created easy game. I added two circular progressBar in setTimeout, but still doesn't work as i expect. I wanna to these bars goes from 0 to 100% and finish. Unfortunately second of them is 2 times quicker than first. If I try add only one bar, there's not problem. I add my program on GH, there I selected the most important lines. I'm sorry for my english, I'm not native :/

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kalam&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font/flaticon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">



    <title>ColorGame</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-layer">
        <h1 class="title">Remember this color! </h1>
        <div class="square draw-square">
            <!-- <div class="my-progress-bar"></div> -->
        </div>
        <div class="button-box">
            <button class="button drawButton">Draw Color</button>
            <button class="button listButton">Your scores</button>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="check-layer">
        <div class="square player-square">
            <!-- <div class="my-progress-bar"></div> -->
        </div>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="range" class="redInput" value="0" min="0" max="255">
            <input type="range" class="greenInput" value="0" min="0" max="255">
            <input type="range" class="blueInput" value="0" min="0" max="255">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="end-layer">
        <div class="result-text"></div>
        <div class="compare-box">
            <div class="draw-square square-modifier"></div>
            <div class="player-square square-modifier"></div>
        </div>
        <i class="flaticon-close cross"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="list-layer">
            <h1 class="list-title">Scores</h1>

            <i class="flaticon-close"></i>
        </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugin.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

SCSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Kalam', cursive;
}

@mixin flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
:root {
    --drawRed: 0;
    --drawGreen: 0;
    --drawBlue: 0;

    --checkRed: 0;
    --checkGreen: 0;
    --checkBlue: 0;
}

$lightRed: rgb(192, 0, 0);
$mediumRed: rgb(80, 1, 1);
$darkRed: rgb(37, 0, 0);

$lightGreen: rgb(25, 146, 21);
$mediumGreen: rgb(11, 61, 9);
$darkGreen: rgb(3, 17, 2);

$lightBlue: rgb(16, 61, 185);
$mediumBlue: rgb(5, 21, 63);
$darkBlue: rgb(2, 8, 24);

body {
    height: 100vh;
}

// main-layer
.main-layer {
    @include flex();
    position: absolute;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #171717;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: .5em;

}


.title, .description {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-shadow: .05em .05em .01em black; 
}

.square {
    border: .1rem solid white;
    width: 30vw;
    height: 30vw;
    border-radius: 1em;
}

.draw-square {
    @include flex();
    background-color: rgb(var(--drawRed), var(--drawGreen), var(--drawBlue));
}
.my-progress-bar {
    position: relative;
}

.progress-percentage {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgba(0,0,0, .1)
}
.button-box {
    @include flex();
    width: 100%;
}
.button {
    width: 7rem;
    height: 2.2rem;
    background-color: rgb(223, 70, 0);
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1rem;
    border: none;
    border-radius: .5em;  
    margin: 0 .5em; 
    text-shadow: .07em .07em .05em black; 
    box-shadow: 
    inset -.1em -.1em .2em .05em rgb(95, 30, 0),
    .03em .03em .01em .01em rgb(12, 4, 0);
    transition: 1s;
    &:hover {
        background-color: rgb(95, 30, 0);
        box-shadow: 
    inset -.1em -.1em .2em .05em rgb(27, 9, 0),
    .03em .03em .01em .01em rgb(12, 4, 0);
    }
}


// check-layer

.check-layer {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #171717;
}

.player-square {
    @include flex();
    background-color: rgb(var(--checkRed), var(--checkGreen), var(--checkBlue));
}

.input-box {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 30vw;
    height: 50vw;
}



input {
    // position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1rem;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 1rem;
}



input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: .1rem;
    height: .1rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.redInput::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 .3rem $lightRed;
    border: .5rem solid $darkRed;
}

.greenInput::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 .3rem $lightGreen;
    border: .5rem solid $darkGreen;
}

.blueInput::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 .3rem $lightBlue;
    border: .5rem solid $darkBlue;
}




.redInput {
    background-color: $mediumRed;
    box-shadow:  .1em 0 .3em .1em $darkRed;

}

.greenInput {
    background-color: $mediumGreen;
    box-shadow:  .1em 0 .3em .1em $darkGreen;
}

.blueInput {
    background-color: $mediumBlue;
    box-shadow:  .1em 0 .3em .1em $darkBlue;
}
// end-layer

.end-layer {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #171717;
}

.compare-box {
    display: flex;
}

.square-modifier {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 50vw;
}

.result-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: .02em .02em .03em black;
}

.flaticon-close::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: .3em;
    right: .3em;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: .04em .04em .02em black;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0;
}

// list

.list-layer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 1em 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.list-title {
    @include flex();
    font-size: 4em;
    color: rgb(223, 70, 0);
}

.score {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: white;   
}


@media (min-width: 768px) {
    html {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
    .square {
        width: 25vw;
        height: 25vw;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    html {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
    }
    .square {
        width: 35vw;
        height: 35vw;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1366px) {
    html {
        font-size: 3rem;
    }
    .square {
        width: 40vw;
        height: 40vw;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1500px) {
    html {
        font-size: 3rem;
    }
    .square {
        width: 30vw;
        height: 30vw;
    }
}


@media (orientation:portrait) {

    // main-layer
    .main-layer {
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
    .title {
        font-size: 2rem;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .button {
        width: 70vw;
        height: 2.5rem;
        margin: .5em 0;
    }
    .square {
        width: 90vw;
        height: 90vw;
    }
    .button-box {
        flex-direction: column;
    }


    // check-layer
    .check-layer {
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .input-box {
        justify-content: space-between;
        width: 80%;
        height: 50vw;
    }

    // end-layer

    .compare-box {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .square-modifier {
        height: 50vh;
        width: 100vw;
    }
}
@media (orientation:portrait) and (min-width: 375px) {
    html {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
}
@media (orientation:portrait) and (min-width: 768px) {
    html {
        font-size: 1.7rem;
    }
    .input-box {
        height: 25vw;
    }
}
```

JavaScript

```
const checkDuration = 7000;
const fadeDuration = 1000;
const progressBar = [];
const score = [];

let squareSize;
let currentPercent;
let scoreCounter = 0;

// wylosowane kolory na samym początku
let drawRed = 0;
let drawGreen = 0;
let drawBlue = 0;

// kolory ustawione przez player'a
let checkRed = 0;
let checkGreen = 0;
let checkBlue = 0;

// timeoutsy
let firstTimeOut = 0;
let secondTimeOut = 0;

function addScore() {
    score[scoreCounter] = $('<div>').addClass('score').text((scoreCounter+1) + ".  " + currentPercent);
    $('.list-layer').append(score[scoreCounter]);
}
function randNumber(min, max) {
    return Math.round(Math.random()*max + min);
}
function setCssVariable(cssVariable, currentValue) {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty(cssVariable, currentValue);
    // console.log(cssVariable+", "+currentValue)
}
function updateValue(cssVariable,  sliderClass) {  
    setCssVariable(cssVariable, parseInt($(sliderClass).val())); // ustawia zmienną css'ową na daną wartość slidera
    setGlobalVariable(sliderClass)
}
function setGlobalVariable(sliderClass) {
    if(sliderClass == '.redInput') {
        checkRed = parseInt($(sliderClass).val());
    }
    else if(sliderClass == '.greenInput'){
        checkGreen = parseInt($(sliderClass).val());
    } 
    else  {
        checkBlue = parseInt($(sliderClass).val());
    }
}
function setColor() { // <<< -----------------------------------  FIRST TIMEOUT 
    firstTimeOut = setTimeout(()=> {
        checkLayer();
        console.log("check-layer")
    }, checkDuration)
}

function deleteProgressBar() {
    $(progressBar[0]).remove();
    $(progressBar[1]).remove();
}

function addProgressBar(numberBar, destination) {
            progressBar[numberBar] = $('<div>').addClass('my-progress-bar');
            $(destination).append(progressBar[numberBar]);
            $(progressBar[numberBar]).circularProgress({
                width: squareSize,
                height: squareSize,
                line_width:10,
                color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .25)",
                starting_position: 0,
                percent: 0
                // counter_clockwise: false
            }).circularProgress('animate', 100, checkDuration); // <<< --------------------- checkDuration
}

function fadeLayer(show, element, duration) {
    if(show) {
        $(element).css('display', 'flex').fadeIn(duration); // odkrywa się check-layer
    } else {
        $(element).css('display', 'none').fadeOut(duration); // odkrywa się check-layer
    }

}

function checkLayer() {
    // $(progressBar[0]).remove(); 
    fadeLayer(true, '.check-layer', fadeDuration);
    addProgressBar(1, '.check-layer .player-square'); 

    secondTimeOut = setTimeout(()=>{ /////////////////////   <<< ------------------------------ SECOND TIMEOUT 
        compareColors();
        addScore();
        fadeLayer(true, '.end-layer', fadeDuration);
        scoreCounter++;
    }, checkDuration);

}

function compareColors() {

    // algoryt I

    // const redDeviation = drawRed-checkRed
    // const greenDeviation = drawGreen-checkGreen;
    // const blueDeviation = drawBlue-checkBlue;
    // // const distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(redDeviation, 2) + Math.pow(greenDeviation, 2) + Math.pow(blueDeviation, 2))
    // // const percent = Math.floor(100 - (distance/Math.sqrt(3*Math.pow(255, 2)))*100) +"%";
    // const distance = Math.sqrt(redDeviation*redDeviation + greenDeviation*greenDeviation + blueDeviation*blueDeviation);
    // console.log(distance)
    // const percent = Math.floor(100 - (distance/442)*100) +"%"


// algorytm II
    const rmean = (drawRed+checkRed)/2;
    const r = drawRed-checkRed
    const g = drawGreen-checkGreen;
    const b = drawBlue-checkBlue;
    const weightR = 2 + rmean/256;
    const weightG = 4.0;
    const weightB = 2 + (255-rmean)/256;
    const d1 =  Math.sqrt(weightR*r*r + weightG*g*g + weightB*b*b);
    const maxColDist = 764.8339663572415;
    const s1 = Math.round(((maxColDist-d1)/maxColDist)*100) + "%";
    currentPercent = s1;
    $('.result-text').text(s1);
}

function drawButton() {
    $('.drawButton').click(()=> {
        // dodaje progressBar
        addProgressBar(0, '.main-layer .draw-square');
        // zablokowanie przycisku
        $('.drawButton').prop('disabled', true);
        $('.listButton').prop('disabled', true);

        // losuje liczby do rgb() w css'ie
        drawRed = randNumber(0, 255);
        drawGreen = randNumber(0, 255);
        drawBlue = randNumber(0, 255);

        // ustawia zmiennym wylosowaną wartość
        setCssVariable('--drawRed', drawRed)
        setCssVariable('--drawGreen', drawGreen)
        setCssVariable('--drawBlue', drawBlue)   

        setColor(); // <<< -------------------------- ODPALA SIĘ TIMEOUT NR1
    })
}
function sliders() {
    $('.redInput').on('change mousemove touchmove', updateValue.bind(this, "--checkRed", '.redInput'));
    $('.greenInput').on('change mousemove touchmove', updateValue.bind(this, "--checkGreen", '.greenInput'));
    $('.blueInput').on('change mousemove touchmove', updateValue.bind(this, "--checkBlue", '.blueInput'));  
}
function cross() {
    $('.cross').click(() => {
        restart();
    })
}
function setDefaultSliderPosition() {
    $('.redInput').val(0);
    $('.greenInput').val(0);
    $('.blueInput').val(0);
}
function restart() {
    $('.drawButton').prop('disabled', false); // odblokowanie przycisku
    $('.listButton').prop('disabled', false); // odblokowanie przycisku
    fadeLayer(false, '.check-layer', 0);
    fadeLayer(false, '.end-layer', 0);
    setCssVariable('--drawRed', 0);
    setCssVariable('--drawGreen', 0);
    setCssVariable('--drawBlue', 0);
    setCssVariable('--checkRed', 0);
    setCssVariable('--checkGreen', 0);
    setCssVariable('--checkBlue', 0);
    setDefaultSliderPosition();
    deleteProgressBar();
    clearTimeout(secondTimeOut); // <<<------------------------- CLEAR TIMEOUTS
    clearTimeout(firstTimeOut); 
}
function list() {
    $('.listButton, .list-layer .flaticon-close').click(() => { 
        $('.list-layer').slideToggle(1500, 'easeOutBounce');
    }); 
}

function resize() {
    $(window).on('resize', () => {
        squareSize = $('.square').css("width");
    });
}

$('.list-layer').fadeOut(0);

// funckje nasłuchujące
drawButton();
sliders();
cross();  
list();
resize();
```

Comment: you should put the code to reproduce the problem in your question because if you change your github code this question will no longer be valid

Comment: As above, click the snippet button when editing your question and provide html/css/js (as required) to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: // funkcje nasłuchujący :) Spróbuj zrobić jsfiddle wtedy każdy będzie mógł spróbować naprawić na bieżąco